# Should I add a new answer or edit a previous one

Tags: discussion, answers, etiquette, questions, multiple-answers

Two solutions to the same problem have occurred to me within a few days. I tried to add the alternative solution, but the system suggested to edit my previous one. Should I add a new answer or edit a previous one in cases like this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This happens occasionally, and the results have also been varied. In some cases, users provide multiple solutions in a single answer ([example](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/54057/5764)). In other instances, users may provide multiple answers, each of which provide a distinct solution approach ([example query](http://data.stackexchange.com/tex/query/322524/questions-with-multiple-answers-by-the-same-user)). The former scenario is more the norm in my opinion.

The original question may request each answer to identify a separate instance/solution ([example](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/782/5764)). However, if there's no such requirement set out, it depends on the answerer.

The system allows it, even though it provides a prompt when attempting to do so, so make sure it's not an addition to an existing answer and/or that it can be a "stand-alone, distinct and valid response".

Ultimately the community has a say in whatever choice is made based on their voting behaviour. That is, if it's considered more of an edit to an existing answer rather than a separate answer, I'm sure community members will raise the question in comments (perhaps [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41/tex-latex-and-friends)), or via their voting.

[Meta.SE](http://meta.stackexchange.com) references:

- [What is the official etiquette on answering a question twice?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/25209/168244)
- [Can a question be answered twice by the same person?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/116426/168244)